# Using memcpy trying to copy one struct into a char[] buffer

Tags: c++, c

```
#define ECHOMAX 100

struct tDataPacket
{
    int iPacket_number;
    char sData[ECHOMAX];
};

int main () {
    tDataPacket packet;
    packet.iPacket_number=10;
    strcpy(packet.sData,"Hello world");
    char buffer[sizeof(tDataPacket)];

    memcpy(buffer,&packet.iPacket_number,sizeof(int));
    memcpy(buffer+sizeof(int),packet.sData,ECHOMAX);

    std::cout<<"Buffer = "<<buffer<<"END";
  return 0;
}
```

In the above code I am trying to pack my structure in a char[] buffer so that I can send it to a UDP socket. But the output of the program is "" string. So nothing is getting copied to 'buffer'. Am I missing anything??

Comment: When you copy the int, at least one of the first (sizeof(int)) characters of buffer will be zero, which will terminate the string output.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg,
Actually there is no variable length arrays in this code, because all array sizes are constants. 

ECHOMAX is defined constant, when sizeof(tDataPacket) is constant because result type of sizeof is compile-time constant regardless of it's argument.

Comment: @rasen You're right, must have misread.

Answer (score 4):

When you copy the int, at least one of the first "n" characters of the buffer will be zero (where "n" is the size of an int on your platform).  For example for a 4-byte int:

```
x00 x00 x00 x0a   or   x0a x00 x00 x00
```

Depending on the endianness of your processor.

Printing out the zero will have the effect of terminating the output string.

Answer (score 3):

You have no code to sensibly print the contents of the buffer, so you are expecting this to work by magic. The stream's `operator <<` function expects a pointer to a C-style string, which the buffer isn't.

Comment: @SoumyajitRoy Because what you have is not a string, but the byte representation of the struct disguised in a `char` buffer. ***Think about it.***

Comment: @SoumyajitRoy it interprets the `char[]` buffer as a [null terminated string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string). So it prints characters until it finds a `0`. And it looks like the first element is a `0`.

Comment: @SoumyajitRoy: No, it won't work. It has no idea what would be a sensible way to output your buffer. How could it? Where is the code to output a structure consisting of an integer followed by a string in a format sensible to humans? That code does not exist, so expecting it to happen is unreasonable.

Answer (score 1):

It's `""` because `int iPacket_number` is probably laid out in memory as:

```
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x0a
```

which is an empty string (`nul`-terminator in the first character).

Firstly you probably want some sort of marshalling so that the on-the-wire representation is well established and portable (think endian differences between platforms).

Secondly you shouldn't need to "print" the resulting string; it makes no sense.

Thirdly you want `unsigned char`, not (signed) `char`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't print an integer as text, because it's not text.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do a loop (or something like that) to print the actual contents of the buffer:

```
 std::cout << "Buffer=";
 for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(tDataPacket); i++)
 {
    std::cout << hex << (unsigned int)buffer[i] << " ";
    if ((i & 0xf) == 0xf) std::cout << endl;   // Newline every 16. 
 }
 std::cout << "END" << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this but it's not really relevant to display binary data like that:

```
std::cout<<"Buffer = "; for each (auto c in buffer)
{
    std::cout<< c; 
} 
std::cout <<"END";
```